# T-SQL: How does one handle an error in a print statement?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, error-handling

In printing out some calculated values that involve division to calculate a percentage I'm receiving a divide by zero error. I'm not worried that it is happening, I just want to know how I can print a 0 along with the rest of the line instead of it printing the error, ie 0%.

This is my print statement:

```
print cast(@usercode as varchar) + ' ' + @username + space(4) +
    'cr' + space(4) + cast(@totalUserVolumeCredit as varchar) + 
    space(4) + cast(@userUnpaids as varchar) + space(4) + 
    cast(@userDisputes as varchar) + space(4) + 
    cast((@userUnpaids + @userDisputes) as varchar) + space(4) + 
    cast(((@userUnpaids + @userDisputes)/@totalUserVolumeCredit) as varchar) + --error line
    space(4) + cast(@userRedirectsVolume as varchar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print cast(@usercode as varchar) + ' ' + @username + space(4) +
     'cr' + space(4) + cast(@totalUserVolumeCredit as varchar) + 
     space(4) + cast(@userUnpaids as varchar) + space(4) + 
     cast(@userDisputes as varchar) + space(4) + 
     cast((@userUnpaids + @userDisputes) as varchar) + space(4) + 
     case @totalUserVolumeCredit when 0 then '0' else
        cast(((@userUnpaids + @userDisputes)/@totalUserVolumeCredit) as varchar)
     end +
     space(4) + cast(@userRedirectsVolume as varchar);
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/2079)

Comment: By the looks of things this would just print `0` if `@totalUserVolumeCredit` is 0? That's not what I meant in my question: I meant if that variable is zero (and thus would cause the divide by zero error) then still print the rest of the line  as well as 0%, instead of just spitting out the error message.

Comment: @Logan: Ah, sorry, then I got your question wrong. The solution is the same, though, it's just a matter of where you put the condition. I've updated my code above.

Answer (score 1):

Your print statement is complex. I would suggest breaking up the calculations and assigning variables and then printing the result. You can use [T-SQL if/else](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182587.aspx) like this:

```
declare @calculation varchar(20)

if @totalUserVolumeCredit = 0
    set @calculation = '0%'
else
    set @calculation = cast((@userUnpaids + @userDisputes)/@totalUserVolumeCredit as varchar)

print cast(@usercode as varchar) + ' ' + @username + space(4) +
    'cr' + space(4) + cast(@totalUserVolumeCredit as varchar) + 
    space(4) + cast(@userUnpaids as varchar) + space(4) + 
    cast(@userDisputes as varchar) + space(4) + 
    cast((@userUnpaids + @userDisputes) as varchar) + space(4) + 
    @calculation  + -- former error line
    space(4) + cast(@userRedirectsVolume as varchar);
```

Or, beginning with SQL Server 2005 you can use [try/catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). Simple example:

```
DECLARE @x int SET @x = 5
DECLARE @y int SET @y = 0

begin try
    PRINT @x / @y
end try
begin catch
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
end catch
```

With try/catch you put the troublesome calculation into a try/catch block and deal with it in whatever manner is appropriate for your problem domain.

Comment: This route required a lot more changes to my code (this was a repeated problem) so I rather used David's answer. Still a good idea though :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just change this expression:

```
(@userUnpaids + @userDisputes) / @totalUserVolumeCredit
```

like this:

```
isnull((@userUnpaids + @userDisputes) / nullif(@totalUserVolumeCredit, 0), 0)
```

and you would always be getting 0 out of it when the divisor was 0.

This is how it works:

1. [`nullif()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) replaces the divisor with NULL when it's 0.
2. Because of the NULL divisor, the result of the expression becomes NULL.
3. [`isnull()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) turns the NULL result into 0. (You could also use the more standard [`coalesce()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) instead.)